# How to make a dd stay with its dt in a column layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a layout with `column-width: 20em;` that contains a definition list. Sometimes a `dt` will get stranded at the bottom of a column and it's `dd` is at the top of the next column.

There's a [live example here](http://codepen.io/notionparallax/pen/FljqB). (Although not totally cleanly cut down to a minimal example.)

[image]

See the bottom of the first and third columns.

I know I can control the breaks inside an element with widows, orphans and column-break-inside, but is there a way to make the two elements behave as one?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149745/keep-a-heading-with-the-following-text) is about a similar problem, but it doesn't feel like each `dt` `dd` pair is semantically a section.

Comment: Please show us some code that replicates the problem. A screenshot would also be helpful.

Comment: Good point, I was being (not uncharacteristically) lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although multi-column layout as such is relatively widely supported in modern browsers, the control of [column breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-breaks) is poorly implemented. Implementations mostly support just prevention of column breaks inside an element, not after or before an element. Thus, although you could in theory use `break-before` or `break-after` property, you need to use `break-inside` in practice. (According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after), IE 10+ supports `break-after: avoid-column`, but setting it on `dt` did not seem to have any effect on IE 11.)

You cannot use anything except `dt` and `dd` inside a `dl`. This is not just a formal rule; browsers actually enforce it, ignoring any attempts at using a wrapper around a `dt` and a `dd`. This is really a design flaw in the very `dl` element.

Thus, what you can do is to use other markup instead of `dl`, e.g.

```
<div class=dl>
  <div class=pair>
    <div class=dt>...</div>
    <div class=dt>...</div>
  </div>
  <div class=pair>
    <div class=dt>...</div>
    <div class=dt>...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

You can then style it this way:

```
.dl {
  -webkit-column-width: 20em;
  -moz-column-width: 20em;
  column-width: 20em;
}
.dd { 
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.pair {
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This prevents the undesired column breaks in modern versions of IE and in Chrome. I’m afraid there’s no way to make it work on Firefox.

**Update:** It seems that if you wrap the `<div class=pair>` element inside a single-cell table, `<table><tr><td><div class=pair>...</div></table>`, then Firefox does not break that element in column formatting. Perhaps the reason is that it generally tries to avoid column breaks inside a table cell, which is rather sensible.

Comment: One day soon... It isn't super important at the moment, so I'll just throw the css that's supposed to work in and then one day it'll just magically look better.

Comment: You saved my day. To fix firefox problem, you can just add `overflow: hidden` inside `pair` class

Comment: 9 years later, but Edge at least seems to obey {break-after:avoid-column;} just fine. So @Ben's idea to put in the correct CSS and hope was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

This took a while! @Martha pointed out that this now works in Edge, and I just checked and it works in chrome.

If you set the `dt` to have:

```
dt {  break-after:avoid-column; }
```

Then it'll stay with whatever is behind it. You can try adding it to the demo in the question and it magically works.